# Is there a way of creating truer scalable vector graphics with Tikz? (Or is that a limitation of PDF itself?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, eps, svg

I'm trying to create graphics with TikZ, but the results I on my screen disappoint me a bit. I don't know if it's TikZ or maybe a PDF limitation. Here's an example, zoomed in at 1,000% (I'm using VS Code's Preview):

[image: zoom 1,000%]

We can clearly see that it's pixelated. I zoomed in that much to make things clearer, but I can see the pixelation way earlier.

The code I've used to generate that picture is in [this repo](https://github.com/psygo/latex-go-diagrams-template), and is nothing special. I pretty much used the basic recipes for drawing circles and numbers:

```tex
% Inside a macro...
\draw[draw = black, line width = 0.1mm, fill = white]
  (#2, #3) circle [smooth, radius = 0.25cm];
```

Is this supposed to happen? Is there a way of improving this?

I wonder if this is pixelated because the units I've used are "concrete", i.e., `mm` or `cm` instead of something more arbitrary or general...

What I was looking for is something closer to the apparently true vector graphics of something like the book [Think Like a Pro Haengma, by Young Sun Yoon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CQYSS125):

[image: Go book on Kindle]

But I wonder if that's happening because of Kindle, maybe PDF can't handle it.

For example, I've tried also zooming in at 1,000% a [Go book translation I've made](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/traducao_como_jogar_go/releases/tag/1.0) in which I've used the software [GoWrite2](https://www.gowrite.net/GOWrite2.html) to create EPS images, and the results look similar zoomed in, though they look a bit better at lower zooms or with no zoom at all in my opinion:

[image: GoWrite2 at 1,000%]

Comment: Try a different pdf viewer

Comment: tikz is making vector graphics, although there are choices to be made about how to approximate a circle using bezier curves

Comment: If I ask convert (image magick) to convert the pdf from my code in the long answer-comment, then it happily makes a 12000px by 12000px PNG with smooth edges. So I'm suspicious about your way of determining whether what you see on screen is vector graphics or not.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. Apparently, this was a matter of a bad PDF viewer indeed. I feel awkward about it, and I don't know to whom I should award an answer, sorry.

Comment: For the future viewers perhaps you just mention in the quesiton which viewers and on which operating systems you were using. It is velknown that not all PDF viewers are equated equal and not all are avaible on all systems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved by comments and switching to a different pdf-viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for comment)

I have no issues in scaling the PDF generated by the code below.

The curves are smooth even at 3200% in Evince.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[draw = black, line width = 1pt, fill = white,fill=black]
  (0, 0) circle [smooth, radius = 5mm];
  \draw[draw = black, line width = 1pt, fill = white]
  (0, 1) circle [smooth, radius = 5mm];
  \draw[draw = black, line width = 1pt, fill = white,fill=black]
  (1, 1) circle [smooth, radius = 5mm];
  \draw[draw = black, line width = 1pt, fill = white]
  (1,0) circle [smooth, radius = 5mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: On my Mac, Evince seems to reach at most 551.6%. Did you manage to get to 3200% without any tweaks?

Comment: But it is definitely true that Evince shows the PDF way way better than the one I was using.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Make the image sizes smaller. Note that I do not agree with your edits. This was not meant as an answer, but as a comment as you did not provide a full MWE that others could use. Though it is ok you use is as a means to mark the question closed